# providing user input tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I have a scenario where I am uploading a text file then providing a user input and then according to the user input processing further.

Sample file :

```
DOWN 07.11.2016 08:21:33 - 07.11.2016 08:22:33
UP   07.11.2016 09:41:07 - 09.11.2016 09:20:33
DOWN 09.11.2016 08:26:33 - 09.11.2016 08:35:33
UP   09.11.2016 08:23:33 - 09.11.2016 08:25:33
DOWN 09.11.2016 08:36:33 - 09.11.2016 08:38:33
DOWN 10.11.2016 08:36:33 - 10.11.2016 08:38:33
```

code :

```
try:
    import Tkinter as Tk
    import tkFileDialog as fileDialog
except ImportError:
    import tkinter as Tk
    fileDialog = Tk.filedialog

import datetime

def user_input():
current_date = my_entry.get()

def processText(lines):
    total = 0
    start = None
    for k, line in enumerate(lines):
        direction, date1, time1, _, date2, time2 = line.split()
        if direction != "Down": continue
        if start==None: start = date1 + ' ' + time1
        # 1
        D1, M1, Y1 = date1.split('.')
        h1, m1, s1 = time1.split(':')
        # 2
        D2, M2, Y2 = date2.split('.')
        h2, m2, s2 = time2.split(':')
        # Timestamps
        t1 = datetime.datetime(*map(int, [Y1, M1, D1, h1, m1, s1])).timestamp()
        t2 = datetime.datetime(*map(int, [Y2, M2, D2, h2, m2, s2])).timestamp()
        total += (t2-t1)
    return total, start

def openFile():
    filename = fileDialog.askopenfilename()

    fileHandle = open(filename, 'r')
    down, start = processText(fileHandle.readlines())
    txt = "Total Downtime is {0} min from {1}".format(down//60, start)
    textVar.set(txt)

    fileHandle.close()

root = Tk.Tk()

button = Tk.Button(root, text="Open", command=openFile)
button.grid(column=1, row=1)

textVar = Tk.StringVar(root)
label = Tk.Label(root, textvariable=textVar)
label.grid(column=1, row=2)

root.mainloop()
```

Above gives me output as Total Downtime is

```
12 min from 07.11.2016 08:21:33
```

but here I am trying to introduce the user input for DATE and for example if I want to get the downtime from 09.11.2016 then it should prompt me for selecting a date and output(total downtime) should be from the selected date.

Any help would be great!!

EDIT 1 (Added o/p):

traceback :

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
 File "C:/Users/angelina/Desktop/test2/tinkteruser.py", line 34, in read_data
t1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(dt1, "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\_strptime.py", line 565, in     _strptime_datetime
tt, fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\_strptime.py", line 362, in _strptime
(data_string, format))
ValueError: time data 'able   22.06.2017 1' does not match format  '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S
```

Comment: maybe create two functions - first only to load all data to memory 9and maybe you could keep it as datetimes, not strings, second to calculate `total` based on `date`. You could use `pandas` to read file  and search data in table easily.

Comment: @furas I am pretty new to python, Could you help me with that ? It would be great.
Also to add will I get the display of output  ?

Comment: traceback shows `'able   22.06.2017 1'` so you have different data in file and it doesn't match to slicing `line[:4]`, `line[5:24]`, `line[27:46]`

Comment: I have same data in same format but dates and time are different also to note I have 24 hrs format in my file for time values.

Comment: The above error occurs when i try to provide a range of date.Also to add once I select and run the file and calculate downtime , 2nd time on same it doesn't allow me to run a another file , I need to close the program and then run again for a new file downtime calculation

Comment: error shows that you  have longer text than `"DOWN"` and `"UP  "` and date is in different place in string (it doesn't start at 6th char) so slicing will not work and you have to use `split()`.

Comment: Thanks,
but the window opens very small and text displayed is confusing , Is it possible to show the output as well as save it in a text file ? and if I am opening another samplefile1it should add the same in next.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read file once and calculate for different dates.

[image]

btw: as extension it could get few dates in `Entry` (separated by space or comma) and calculate `total` for every date, or calculate in range of two dates

---

In `read_data()` it loads all data and convert to datetimes using

```
datetime.datetime.strptime(date1 + ' ' + time1, "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

In `calculate` it get data from `Entry` and execute `processText()` with data from file and date from entry.

It convert string with data from `Entry` into `datetime`. String may have incorrect date or in unexpeted format so I use `try/except`.

It use `t1 <= selected_date` to compare two `datetime`.

It uses `(t2-t1).seconds` to get seconds between two dates (without using `timestamp()`). It could do this even in `read_data()`.

Full code:

Problem can be `except Exception as ex:` which is incorrect in Python 2.

```
try:
    import Tkinter as Tk
    import tkFileDialog as fileDialog
except ImportError:
    import tkinter as Tk
    import tkinter.filedialog as fileDialog

import datetime



def read_data():
    '''
    Read data from file and convert to list with datetime
    which can be used to calculate time and display.
    '''
    global data

    filename = fileDialog.askopenfilename()

    if filename:
        # read all lines
        with open(filename) as fileHandle:
            lines = fileHandle.readlines()

        # convert to `datetime` (not `timestamp`)
        data = []        
        for line in lines:
            direction, date1, time1, _, date2, time2 = line.split()

            t1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(date1 + ' ' + time1, "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")
            t2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(date2 + ' ' + time2, "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")

            data.append([direction, t1, t2])

        print(data)


def processText(lines, selected_date):

    total = 0
    start = None

    # if there is `selected_date` then convert to `datetime`
    if selected_date:
        try:
            selected_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(selected_date, "%d.%m.%Y")
        except Exception as ex:
            print("ERROR:", ex)
            selected_date = None

    # calculate time
    for direction, t1, t2 in lines:

        if direction == "DOWN":

            # if `selected_date` then filter times
            if selected_date and t1 <= selected_date:
                continue

            if not start:
                start = t1

            total += (t2-t1).seconds//60

    return total, start.strftime("%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")

def calculate():

    current_date = entry.get().strip()

    down, start = processText(data, current_date)

    txt = "Total Downtime is {0} min from {1}".format(down, start)
    textVar.set(txt)

# --- main ---

data = None # to keep data from file

# -

root = Tk.Tk()

button = Tk.Button(root, text="Open", command=read_data)
button.grid(column=1, row=1)

textVar = Tk.StringVar(root)

label = Tk.Label(root, textvariable=textVar)
label.grid(column=1, row=2)

entry = Tk.Entry(root)
entry.grid(column=1, row=3)

button2 = Tk.Button(root, text="Calculate", command=calculate)
button2.grid(column=1, row=4)

root.mainloop()
```

---

**EDIT:** other changes (keep previous version for comparing)

Now it calculate `(t2-t1).seconds` in `read_data` and it keeps it in `data`

And it convert into minutes after it adds all seconds so it can gives few minutes more.

Now it can calculate for many dates in entry (separated by comma).

It also uses `slicing` to get elements from lines.
I assumed that all data has format like in sample file.

```
DOWN 07.11.2016 08:21:33 - 07.11.2016 08:22:33
UP   07.11.2016 09:41:07 - 09.11.2016 09:20:33
DOWN 09.11.2016 08:26:33 - 09.11.2016 08:35:33
UP   09.11.2016 08:23:33 - 09.11.2016 08:25:33
DOWN 09.11.2016 08:36:33 - 09.11.2016 08:38:33
DOWN 10.11.2016 08:36:33 - 10.11.2016 08:38:33
```

**EDIT:** it seems file can have longer values than `"DOWN"` and `"UP  "` so slicing will not work so I use again `split()` instead of `slicing`

[image]

```
try:
    import Tkinter as Tk
    import tkFileDialog as fileDialog
except ImportError:
    import tkinter as Tk
    import tkinter.filedialog as fileDialog

import datetime



def read_data():
    '''
    Read data from file and convert to list with datetime
    which can be used to calculate time and display.
    '''
    global data

    filename = fileDialog.askopenfilename()

    if filename:
        # read all lines
        with open(filename) as fileHandle:
            lines = fileHandle.readlines()

        # convert to `datetime` (not `timestamp`)
        data = []        
        for line in lines:
            #direction = line[:4].strip()
            #dt1 = line[5:24]
            #dt2 = line[27:46]

            direction, d1, t1, _, d2, t2 = line.split()
            dt1 = d1 + ' ' + t1
            dt2 = d2 + ' ' + t2 

            t1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(dt1, "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")
            t2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(dt2, "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")

            seconds = (t2-t1).seconds

            data.append([direction, t1, t2, seconds])

        print(data)


def processText(lines, selected_date):

    total = 0
    start = None

    print(selected_date)
    # if there is `selected_date` then convert to `datetime`
    if selected_date:
        try:
            selected_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(selected_date, "%d.%m.%Y")
        except AttributeError as ex:
            print("ERROR:", ex)
            selected_date = None

    # calculate time
    for direction, t1, t2, seconds in lines:

        if direction == "DOWN":

            # if `selected_date` then filter times
            if selected_date and t1 <= selected_date:
                continue

            if not start:
                start = t1.strftime("%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")

            total += seconds

    # convert to minutes after summing all second
    total = total//60

    return total, start

def calculate():

    all_dates = entry.get().split(',')
    print(all_dates)
    all_dates = [date.strip() for date in all_dates]

    txt = ''

    for current_date in all_dates:
        down, start = processText(data, current_date)
        txt += "Total Downtime is {0} min from {1}\n".format(down, start)

    textVar.set(txt)

# --- main ---

data = None # to keep data from file

# -

root = Tk.Tk()

button = Tk.Button(root, text="Open", command=read_data)
button.grid(column=1, row=1)

textVar = Tk.StringVar(root)

label = Tk.Label(root, textvariable=textVar)
label.grid(column=1, row=2)

entry = Tk.Entry(root)
entry.grid(column=1, row=3)

button2 = Tk.Button(root, text="Calculate", command=calculate)
button2.grid(column=1, row=4)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, But it raises an error added the stack trace.

Comment: you get error because you have something different in file then you saw as sample file. And then it doesn't fit to slicing `line[:4].strip()`, `line[5:24]`, `line[27:46]`.

Comment: My sample file is not fixed one. It can have various values, so if i want to search in between date range of 3 months for exmple 9.10.2017 to 9.01.2017 then it won't work?

Comment: if you have different values than `"DOWN"` and `"UP  "` (with 2 spaces) - then date is in different place in string and slicing will not work and you have to use `split()` like in first version.

Comment: I changed second code - it uses again `split()` instead of `slicing`. And I moved `.strftime("%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")` from `return total, start.strftime("%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")` to `start = t1.strftime("%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")`

Comment: current version doesn't use two dates as range but as two different dates. If you need constant range ie. 90 days then you can use `datetime.timedelta` - see https://pastebin.com/3gDbiYf9

Comment: Can we add a button as options like last  downtime from  "90 days", "30 days", "7 days"

Comment: you can do what ever you want. If you will have problem then create new question with code and error message. SO is not place to write all code for you.